# Load Custom Image Format C/C++ Binary

Tags: c, image, memory, binary

I'm having many problems trying to load an image file (PIXELIMAGEFORMAT). The code does not get past comparing the magic header value to `PIXELIMAGEFORMAT` (without string ending character)

My Image Format is:

```
Bytes   0-15: PIXELIMAGEFORMAT (The Magic Header Value)
Bytes  16-17: Width            (Formatted as 0000 xxxx xxxx xxxx)
Bytes  18-19: Height           (Formatted as 0000 xxxx xxxx xxxx)
Bytes  20-23: Bits Per Pixel   (Formatted as 1000 1000 1000 1000)
Bytes  24-31: NULL             (All 0's)
Bytes 32-END: 32-Bit RGBA      (8 Bit Red, 8 Bit Green, 8 Bit Blue, 8 Bit Alpha)
```

My Image Loading Code is:

```
char* vimg_LoadPIXELIMAGE(char* filePath) {
  FILE* file;
  file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
  if (file == NULL) return "a";

  char* header = (char*)malloc(32);
  fread(header, sizeof(char), 32, file);
  char* magicHeader = (char*)malloc(16);
  const char magic[] = {
    'P', 'I', 'X', 'E', 'L',
    'I', 'M', 'A', 'G', 'E',
    'F', 'O', 'R', 'M', 'A', 'T'
  };
  strncpy(magicHeader, header, 16);

  if (magicHeader != magic) return "b";

  unsigned short width;
  unsigned short height;

  memcpy(&width, header + 16, 2);
  memcpy(&height, header + 18, 2);

  unsigned int fileSize = width * height;

  char* fullbuffer = (char*)malloc(fileSize+32);
  char* buffer = (char*)malloc(fileSize);
  fread(fullbuffer, 1, fileSize + 32, file);
  memcpy(buffer, fullbuffer + 32, fileSize);

  return buffer;
}
```

My Main Function is:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv) {
  char* imgSRC;
  imgSRC = vimg_LoadPIXELIMAGE("img.pfi");
  if (imgSRC == "a")
    printf("File Is Null!\n");
  else if (imgSRC == "b")
    printf("File Is Not a PIXELIMAGE!\n");
  else if (imgSRC == NULL)
    printf("SEVERE ERROR!!!\n");
  else
    printf(imgSRC);
  system("pause");
}
```

Currently what it *SHOULD* do is print out the char values of each binary pixel.

If you want, I can post my current image file as well.

Thanks!

- Adrian Collado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare the address of the buffers, and not the buffers themselves, you should use `memcmp`:

```
if (memcmp(magicHeader, magic, 16) != 0) return "b";
```

---

This is not the answer, but should also be considered:

You compare addresses, while you should compare the value:

```
if (*imgSRC == 'a')
```

Also, since NULL may be returned , I would change the order of checks:

```
if (imgSRC == NULL)
    printf("SEVERE ERROR!!!\n");
else if (*imgSRC == 'a')
    printf("File Is Null!\n");
else if (*imgSRC == 'a')
    printf("File Is Not a PIXELIMAGE!\n");
else
    printf(imgSRC);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because `*imgSRC` is the memory location. `imgSRC` is a char array. Anyways, that is not where the error is. The error occurs when comparing the `magicHeader` with `magic`, which both *DO* have the same value...

Comment: Also.. NULL is not specifically returned... it is there as a safeguard to prevent trying to print a null value. Every time I run the code, it prints the "File is Not a PIXELIMAGE!" string.

Comment: That fixed the File is Not a PIXELIMAGE error, but now I just have to find out why the file is not properly loading.. Guess it's time to experiment!